# Can I detect when my webcam is used by a program on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, command-line-interface

Is there a way to detect when a webcam is being used.

When I join a video call or use Photo Booth, the leds on my Logitech C920 (usb) webcam turn on, I would like to be able to detect that so I can automatically change the color of my "smart" lights.

Either through command line or something that I code, I have done some research but haven't found anything that seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`is-camera-on-cli`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-camera-on-cli) package from the CLI.

Example:

```
$ is-camera-on
✔ Camera is on
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like this will only work for the built in camera though, I want to know when my external camera is in use, ideally when _any_ webcam is in use as I want this to work both when my laptop is docked in and when it's not.